# How can I create a Sizable Winforms form with a fixed3D like border

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am attempting to create a form that looks exactly like a winforms form with a FormBorderStyle of Fixed3D but I wish for it to be sizable by the user.

How can I achieve this? I'm also using VB if your answer is code related.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Just a FYI, the specific way it is displayed is dependent on the OS of the user. For example, on my win 8.1 pc I see practically no difference between Sizable and Fixed3D.

Comment: Fixed3D means fixed, not sizable.  You can't make it do what you want without changing the FormBorderStyle.

Comment: @ScottWylie - "Fixed means fixed" - No kidding.I didn't say I wanted to use Fixed3D and make it sizable. I said "Looks like". anyway, editing the FormBorderStyle is what I ended up doing with the help of a skin editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Skin Editor (found [here](http://www.skin-soft.co.uk/Products/VisualStyler/Overview.aspx)), I applied some changes to the SizableToolWindow FormBorderStyle and achieved what I wanted.